Nginx Configuration: POST Requests to Laravel API Returning Errors
I am currently facing an issue with my Nginx configuration while trying to handle POST requests for my Laravel API. GET requests work without any problems, but POST requests are returning errors like 502 bad gateway.
Here is my Nginx configuration for the API:
server {
    listen 8080;
    server_name remote_addr;
    index index.php index.html;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    root /var/www/app/public;

    location /api {
        try_files $uri /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass php:9000;  # Changed to local PHP-FPM
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $path_info;
    }
} 

here is docker-compose.yaml file

version: '3.8'

services:
  # Landing service (Next.js)
  landing:
    build:
      context: ./landing
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: landing_page
    ports:
      - "3002:3000"
    networks:
      - app-network

  # Chat service (Next.js )
  chat:
    build:
      context: ./chat
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: chat_app
    ports:
      - "3001:3000"
    networks:
      - app-network

  # Go service (for go-chat)
  go-chat:
    build:
      context: ./go-chat
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: go_chat
    ports:
      - "7070:7070"
    networks:
      - app-network

  # Laravel backend service
  php:
    build:
      context: ./backend  # Backend dizini
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: laravel_backend
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:
        - "9000:9000"
    volumes:
      - ./backend:/var/www/app:delegated  # Uygulama dosyalarını bağlama
    networks:
      - app-network
   
  # PostgreSQL service
  postgres:
    image: postgres:15
    container_name: postgres_db
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: "project"
      POSTGRES_USER: "user"
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: "pass"
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    networks:
      - app-network

  # Nginx service
  nginx:
    image: nginx:alpine
    container_name: nginx_proxy
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    volumes:
      - ./backend:/var/www/app
      - ./nginx/conf.d/:/etc/nginx/conf.d/
    networks:
      - app-network
    depends_on:
      - chat
      - landing
      - php

networks:
  app-network:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  postgres_data:


and laravel Dockerfile

# Base image
FROM php:8.2-fpm

# Install system dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    build-essential \
    libpng-dev \
    libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    locales \
    zip \
    jpegoptim optipng pngquant gifsicle \
    vim \
    unzip \
    git \
    curl \
    libpq-dev \
    && apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Install PHP extensions
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_pgsql

# Set working directory
WORKDIR /var/www/app

# Copy application files
COPY . ./

# Install Composer
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

# Install PHP dependencies
RUN composer install --no-dev --optimize-autoloader

# Set permissions
RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/app/storage /var/www/app/bootstrap/cache \
    && chmod -R 775 /var/www/app/storage /var/www/app/bootstrap/cache

# Expose port 9000 and start php-fpm server
EXPOSE 9000
CMD ["php-fpm"]


thanks for helps
I expected the POST requests to my Laravel API endpoints to work seamlessly after configuring Nginx and resolving the binding issues. Specifically, I anticipated that both GET and POST requests would function correctly, allowing for data retrieval and submission to my Laravel application without errors.

Corresponding nginx error log entries may be useful to help troubleshoot this issue.
